# Sql case statement in where clause to list weeks and months between two dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, case, where-clause

I've just found the `spt_values` table which I found very useful, right now I want list  weeks or months depending on a input parameter `@Month`.

```
DECLARE @start_date [date]       = CAST('2013-08-01' as [date])
DECLARE @end_date [date]         = CAST('2013-10-01' as [date])
DECLARE @Month [bit]  = 0

SELECT
   case @Month when 0 then
              DATEPART(week,DATEADD(WEEK, [v].[number], @start_date))
           else DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, [v].[number], @start_date)) end
           as 'Timespan'
FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values] [v]
WHERE
    DATEADD(WEEK, [v].[number], @start_date) <= @end_date AND
           [v].[type] = 'P'
```

So if I now pass in `@Month = 1` I want to have a where clause like this to list months instead of weeks.

```
WHERE 
CASE @Month WHEN 1 THEN 
 DATEADD(MONTH, [v].[number], @start_date) <= @end_date) when 0 then 
 DATEADD(WEEK, [v].[number], @start_date) <= @end_date) AND
           [v].[type] = 'P'
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work.

I could however have a `If` statement above the `Select` statement witch will work but it would be nice do handle that in the `Where` clause instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
where case @Month
  when 0 then DATEADD(WEEK, [v].[number], @start_date)
  else DATEADD(MONTH, [v].[number], @start_date) end <= @end_date AND
  [v].[type] = 'P'
```

Comment: That wont work cuz Month is of type int and end_date ofc is of type date. Error: Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int. you could try the query urself if you have a sql server instance installed the table spt_values is there

Comment: @Labrinths - Sorry about that. I've updated the answer after running the query.

Comment: Nice work took me a couple of minutes to see the diffrence but now its working thank you :)